# Get questions that haven't been showed from mysql database with php

Tags: php, random

We have a list of questions in a MySQL database and want it to show a random approved question to the user. When you click the Random button, we want another random question to be shown, but not any of the ones the user has already seen.

I'm trying to use something like this (but it doesn't work, just gives a blank page):

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("aldrig") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spg WHERE approved='1'") or die(mysql_error());
$answers = mysql_fetch_array($result);

start_session();

if (isset($_COOKIE["answers"]))
    $alreadyShownAnswers = json_decode($_COOKIE["answers"]);
else
    $alreadyShownAnswers = array();

$answerToShow = $answers[$randomIndex];
$alreadyShownAnswers[] = $answers[$randomIndex];
unset($answers[$randomIndex]);
$answers = array_values($answers);

echo "<div class='contentTitle'><h1>";
echo $answerToShow; 
echo "</h1></div>";

$_COOKIE["answers"] = json_encode(alreadyShownAnswers);

?>
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Is the source blank too, or do the answers just not show up?

Comment: Why not just load all the questions into an array, and then remove them as you present them? This a) reduces calls to the database and b) prevents duplicates.

Comment: Another note: do you want to be using `setcookie()` instead of `$_COOKIE[x] = `?

Comment: The source is blank as well. I would appreciate it very much if some of you could make the finished code that works.  j08691: that sounds like a good idea - would you be able to do that for me?

Comment: The thing is, it needs to be for each individual user. I'm not looking for a new script, just someone who can please fix this one.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong that I can see:

1. You are using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions (not really related to your problem);
2. `mysql_fetch_array` fetches only the first row (one row in general), not all rows from
   the result set;
3. You are not setting `$randomIndex` anywhere.

As it is now, you need to loop through your result set and add all answers to an array. If you switch to for example PDO, you can use [`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to get all results the way you are trying to do now.

You can also use `ORDER BY RAND()` if your database is not too big to get an already randomly ordered result-set you can work with.

Comment: Would you be able to fix that for me?

Comment: My database isn't that large - about 250 questions, so an ORDER BY RAND () would work. What you're saying about fetchAll sounds great - but I don't know how that works. I'm looking for a pretty much ready-to-use code.

Comment: @user1476925 If you're looking for `ready-to-use code` I'm afraid you're at the wrong place...

Comment: Oh. It's not like I'm looking the script (if you know what I mean). Just the modified code that would work.

Comment: The thing is, it needs to be for each individual user. I'm not looking for a new script, just someone who can please fix this one.